# how to get a column with a list of dates between 2 known dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this

```
TicketNo     StartDate   EndDate     Price
TK001   01/04/2014  03/04/2014  3
TK002   02/04/2014  03/04/2014  2
TK003   30/04/2014  02/05/2014  10
```

I am trying to write a select query with 4 columns where there is a new column with a list of dates between StartDate and End Date

like this

```
TicketNo     StartDate   EndDate    DatesBetween     Price
TK001   01/04/2014  03/04/2014  01/04/2014  3
TK001   01/04/2014  03/04/2014  02/04/2014  3
TK001   01/04/2014  03/04/2014  03/04/2014  3
TK002   02/04/2014  03/04/2014  02/04/2014  2
TK002   02/04/2014  03/04/2014  03/04/2014  2
TK003   30/04/2014  02/05/2014  30/04/2014  10
TK003   30/04/2014  02/05/2014  01/05/2014  10
TK003   30/04/2014  02/05/2014  02/05/2014  10
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Do you have a calendar or numbers table?

Comment: SQL Server. We dont have a calendar table.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To make sure you get proper help from the community, please share what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of numbers using `sys.all_objects` and `ROW_NUMBER()`, and join to this table to repeat the dates between:

```
WITH N AS
(   SELECT  Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1
    FROM    sys.all_objects a
            --CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
)
SELECT  T.TicketNo, 
        T.StartDate, 
        T.EndDate, 
        DatesBetween = DATEADD(DAY, N.Number, T.StartDate), 
        T.Price
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN N
            ON N.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, T.StartDate, T.EndDate);
```

If this doesn't generate enough rows, then simply uncomment the cross join in the common table expression.

I would really recommend [a calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql) though. They are very useful, your query would be simpl;ified to:

```
SELECT  T.TicketNo, 
        T.StartDate, 
        T.EndDate, 
        DatesBetween = c.Date, 
        T.Price
FROM    T
        INNER JOIN dbo.Calendar AS c
            ON c.Date >= T.StartDate
            AND c.Date <= T.EndDate;
```

Should the task get more complicated, e.g. geting just working days between two dates including public holidays, then the inital query gets complicated, but with a calendar table this is a very easy change to make.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select t.TicketNo, t.StartDate, t.StartDate as DateBetween, t.EndDate, t.Price 
      from mytable t
      union all
      select cte.TicketNo, cte.StartDate, dateadd(day, 1, cte.DateBetween), cte.EndDate, cte.Price
      from cte
      where cte.DateBetween < cte.EndDate
)
select *
from CTE;
```

Comment: Recursive CTEs do not scale well at all ([demonstrated here](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)), I would steer clear of this approach for large amounts of data, even on a [sample of 5000 records](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/445eb/1) I consistently get execution times 2 or 3 seconds slower than when using a method that doesn't use loops (tested on my local instance of 2012).